# How to get Ubuntu running on VMWare Player?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

ok, I have downloaded a linux .iso and the VMWare player, but I'm missing a VM file to allow me to run the OS in the VM - how do I create this file, or where do i get one from?

thanks

Comment: Use VMWare Server to create a virtual machine, install Ubuntu on it, then use VMWare player to "play" it. VMWare is _not_ easy to use, but it's very robust and has much better hardware hooks (in my experience) than either VirtualBox or Virtual PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an Ubuntu 9.04 Desktop VM from http://linhost.info/vmware/ . Download, unzip using 7-zip (free download), create a user account and delete the default user.

I've also used Virtualbox and setup Ubuntu by mounting the image and running the install, but downloading a pre-made VM is much faster and I've found VMWare Player to be more stable than VirtualBox and faster to save state on exits.

Comment: Also, Check out http://ubuntuguide.net/install-vmware-tools-on-ubuntu-904 for a convenient script to install vmware tools which which made window resizing work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'll retract my answer if I'm just outright wrong, but if you're starting with an (installation) .ISO for the O/S (Ubuntu in your case) I think you want to run VMWare Server, not Player.  VMware Server is also free.  My understanding is that Player is for running existing VMs, not typically for creating new ones.

Comment: And by @Diablomarcus' answer it looks like it may be possible to run a LiveCD in the mode you're attempting, although I think that's not the "expected"/out-of-the-box usage.  Still, if it works... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good guide to it:
http://www.virtualization.info/2005/10/how-to-launch-iso-and-use-livecds.html

Basically you use a pre-used file and then hack it a bit.  The instructions are very clear in that post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if VMWare is required for you and I don't like to promote software without permission but I find VMWare to be anything but usable for me.

In my experience, VMWare is extremely verbose and difficult to configure.

I use [Sun Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) for my virtualization solutions.

Sun VBox makes it easy to mount/unmount .iso images to your virtual machine just by a drop-down menu.

Comment: If you're talking about VMware ESX, then I would completely agree but I think overall usability of VMware Server is very comparable to that of VirtualBox.  I use both on a daily basis.